# Copy data from one sheet and move to other problems

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy some rows from a sheet and then paste in other sheet that will contain the data. Later on I will erase the data form the original sheet to be fulfill again and repeat process.

My problem is that, it looks like I'm coping as well the empty cells from the original sheet so when paste for any reason excel consider this empty cell as the last one. More than sure I'm doing something wrong, the macro is this:

```
    Sub CopyTable()
'
' CopyTable Macro
'
'
' Variables
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim StartCell As Range
    Set sht = Worksheets("Form")
    Set StartCell = Range("A9")

'Refresh UsedRange
    Worksheets("Form").UsedRange

'Find Last Row and Column
    LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

'Select Range
    sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select

' Copy range and move to Data sheet
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Data").Select

' Place pointer on cell A1 and search for next empty cell
    Range("A1").Select
        Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop

' Once find, go back once to place on last empty and paste data from Form sheet no formating
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```

Comment: surely this line doesn't compile? `Worksheets("Form").UsedRange`

Comment: Yes it works as expected, but taking some empty rows from "Form" sheet. So when paste on second sheet these empty rows are not considered as empty.

Comment: That line definitely doesn't do anything! I'm just surprised your code even runs...

Comment: For that, whne I repeat agin the process with new datas there are some empty rows between first batch and second.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the data from the form always has an entry in column A - that there are no entries where A is blank but other cells on the row are not blank:

```
 Sub CopyTable()
 Dim sourcesheet As Worksheet
 Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
 Dim Source As Range
 Dim dest As Range
 Dim Startcell As Range
 Set sourcesheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Form")
 Set Startcell = sourcesheet.Range("A9")
 Set Source = sourcesheet.Range(Startcell, Startcell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
 Set DestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
 Set dest = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
  'set dest to next blank row
 Source.Copy dest
 Set dest = DestSheet.Range(dest, dest.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
 dest.Sort key1:=dest.Cells(1, 1)
 'sort to shift blanks to bottom
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your proposal. Yes, on the origin sheet there will be at least data on  A9 cell and some columns more till Z9. Then I can have one row or some of them max 30. I think the problem is that, for any reason, the cells selected in original sheet consider even the empty rows. Not sure if it is because formulas inside. Are there any way how to select just the ones that have data and not formulas?

Comment: Sorry the code you sent do not works at all, I was trying to check where could be the problem but not possible for me.

Comment: If I can on this secction if I find a way how to consider empty the cells with formulas, I think it will be solved. 'Find Last Row and Column
    LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

Answer (score 0):

finally surfing in stackoverflow I found a pice of code that do exactly want I need, so final macro looks like this:

```
Sub CopyTable()
Dim lastVal As Range, sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheets("Form")
Set lastVal = sht.Columns(2).Find("*", sht.Cells(1, 2), xlValues, _
                            xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
Debug.Print lastVal.Address

sht.Range("A9", lastVal).Resize(, 26).Select 'select B:Ag


Selection.Copy
Sheets("Data").Select


Range("A1").Select
    Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop


ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```